# Vector Valued Functions: Parametrize the intersection of 2 surfaces w/ trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

The question asks:

> Parametrize the intersection of the surfaces using trigonometric functions.
>   $$y^2-z^2=x-6$$
>   $$y^2+z^2=81$$
>
> $\mathbf{r}(t)=$  <kbd>____</kbd>

My first step was recognizing $y^2+z^2=81$ as a circle in the $yz$-plane, which could be defined as $y=9\cos(t)$ and $z=9\sin(t)$.

I then thought that I could substitute in the above values of $y$ and $z$ into the equation $\mathbf{r}(t)=\boxed{\langle9\cos(t)-9\sin(t)+6,9\cos(t),9\sin(t)\rangle}$, but apparently that is incorrect.

Any advice to get me untangled and back on the correct path would be much appreciated.

Comment: The equation $y^2+z^2=81$ is not a equation of a circle in the yz-plane, the projection of this surface on the yz-plane is a circle but it is a cylinder with axis (x'x) and radius=9.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ x = y^2 - z^2 + 6 = 81(\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t) + 6 $

The parametrization is $ (81(\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t) + 6, 9\cos t, 9\sin t) $